# React-Widget Component loads without custom styles - until browser refresh

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack

When a new user signs in, and is redirected to the main page, my calendar component (part of react-widgets) won't take the custom styles I gave it as seen below

```
// style.scss

@import "./calendar.scss";       // <----- does not load until browser refresh
@import "./charts.scss";         // <----- loads fine
@import "./dietTable.scss";      // <----- loads fine
...
```

Refreshing the browser loads the styles properly, and everything works fine until signout.

Even closing the browser and returning it to the site later, the calendar styles load - as long as the user's signed-in token is still in localStorage.

It behaves this way during development, as well as in production (when all the css is compiled down to a single file).

Is this a common problem?

------------- setup ------------

```
// feature.jsx (main page)

require('../../style/style.scss');

// webpack.config.js

{
    test: /\.s?css$/,
    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
        fallback: 'style-loader',
        use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader']
    })
}

// the problem was there even when I wasn't extracting the test
// with the plugin
```

Comment: Greetings, could you specify a bit more about your setup? How are you compiling the scss files?

Comment: I updated the code - thanks

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is with the loading of that style? Could your component not be set to the proper className when you log in?

Comment: The classnames and ids are the original ones that came with the widget. .rw-calendar, #rw_1_calendar, #rw_1_calendar_label... I'm assuming they don't change...